# Retrieve POST body rest

Tags: java, rest

okay so i got this frontend react app that when you select a version of a program to use i need to pass that version and all its data to my restful service

so i got like this

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/sleepy-oyster/v2/myResource/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
body JSON.stringify({
         firstParam:this.state.version
      })
    })
```

were "this.state.version" looks like this

```
{resourceURI: "http://nexus.ad.hrm.se/nexus/service/local/reposit…ent/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/", relativePath: "/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/", text: "16.1-SNAPSHOT", leaf: false, lastModified: "2018-04-09 07:04:40.0 UTC", …}
```

so basically a regular object that i want to send as a pathparam and my rest service that gets called looks like

```
 @POST
    @Path("{version}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION JSON)
    public void createOyster(@Context NexusResource version) {

        restUtil.getVersionFromNexus(version);
        }
```

Were the object i send is an NexusResource but all i get is null. anyone know how i can do this?

Here is how the NexusResource class looks like

```
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "resourceURI",
        "relativePath",
        "text",
        "leaf",
        "lastModified",
        "sizeOnDisk"
})
public class NexusResource {
    @JsonProperty("resourceURI")
    private String resourceURI;
    @JsonProperty("relativePath")
    private String relativePath;
    @JsonProperty("text")
    private String text;
    @JsonProperty("leaf")
    private Boolean leaf;
    @JsonProperty("lastModified")
    private String lastModified;
    @JsonProperty("sizeOnDisk")
    private Integer sizeOnDisk;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: You need to send this info in the request body instead of part param. Read this article: http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/jax-rs-pathparam-reading-path-parameters/

Comment: @zappee if you look at the edit do you know why i get null now?

Comment: @novafluff Remove the `@Context` annotation and you are done.

Comment: Do you have a mapper from the JSON body to a `NexusResource` instance?

Comment: @LutzHorn i have never done rest before so no i dont have that.I dont even know what that is but i guess its a way for the JSON to become a NexusResource

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin if i remove the Context i get an null (null). i guess it is the lack of a mapper i added the NexusResource class aswell

Comment: Why do you use "@JsonProperty"? You do not need to use them. This is not correct: "@Context NexusResource version". You need to use "@RequestBody".

Comment: @zappe its used in an old version of the program that i am refreshing the ui of. the older version is still gonna be used so i dont want to change to much of it

Comment: okay, but before you post something to stackoverflow please correct your source snippet.

Answer (score 0):

See annotation [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)

Change your code to something like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/xxx",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public void createOyster(@RequestBody NexusResource version) {...}
```